# qt asynchronous completion for object member

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous-postback

I have a `QObject` class processing requests.  So I could create a SLOT `process(QString)`.  I would like to know when the request was processed - i.e. receive a `future` of some kind that I can wait for.  It should be possible to relate reults to corresponding requests.

But since the SLOT can't return a value, I'm a bit stuck...  Can this be achieved with the Qt SIGNAL/SLOT mechanism?

Comment: If i get this right, you looking for a delivery. so use signal/slot to returning values.

Answer (score 0):

Your slot can emit a signal when it is done (with any data you need as arguments) that you can then connect to, to do other stuff at that point.

Comment: Yes: but how does the receiver know what request this result belongs to?

Comment: @xtofl You connect a specific signal to specific slot.

Comment: I meant: in a 'stream' of requests, a stream of results is emitted, not necessarily in corresponding order.

Comment: @xtofl the signal you emit could contain information on what request it represents the result of.